# C++: implementing multiple instances of an interface or an optional interface in a class

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, interface

I'm having trouble finding best practice information about what I believe should be a fairly common problem pattern.

I will start with a specific (software update related) example, because it makes the discussion more concrete, but the issue should be fairly generic.

Say that I have a software updater interface:

```
struct Software_updater {
    virtual ~Software_updater() = default;
    virtual void action1(const Input1& input1) = 0;
    virtual void action2() = 0;
    virtual bool action3(const Input2& input2) = 0;
    virtual Data1 info1() = 0;
    virtual Data2 info2() = 0;
    // etc.
};
```

For my first implementation `A`, I am lucky, everything is straightforward.

```
class A_software_updater : public Software_updater {
    // ...
};
```

A `B_software_updater`, however, is more complicated. Like in the `A`-case, it is connected to the target to update in a non-trivial manner and maintains a target connection state. But more importantly, it can update two images: the application image, and the boot loader image.

Liking what I have so far, I see no real reason to go for a refactoring, so I assume I can just build upon it. I come up with the following solution:

```
class B_software_updater {
public:
    Software_updater& application_updater() { return application_updater_; }
    Software_updater& boot_loader_updater() { return boot_loader_updater_; }
private:
    class Application_updater : public Software_updater {
        // ...
    } application_updater_;
    class Boot_loader_updater : public Software_updater {
        // ...
    } boot_loader_updater_;
};
```

I.e. I am returning non-`const` references to "interfaces to" member variables. Note that they cannot be `const`, since they mute state.

**Request 1: I think the solution above is a clean one, but I would be happy to get some confirmation**.

In fact, I have recently faced the issue of having to optionally provide an interface in a class, based on compile-time selection of a feature, and I believe the pattern above is a solution for that problem too:

```
struct Optional_interface {
    virtual ~Optional_interface() = default;
    virtual void action1(const Input1& input1) = 0;
    virtual void action2() = 0;
    virtual bool action3(const Input2& input2) = 0;
    virtual Data1 info1() = 0;
    virtual Data2 info2() = 0;
    // etc.
};

class A_implementation {
public:
#ifdef OPTIONAL_FEATURE
    Optional_interface& optional_interface() { return optional_implementation_; }
#endif
    // ...
private:
#ifdef OPTIONAL_FEATURE
    class Optional_implementation : public Optional_interface {
        // ...
    } optional_implementation_;
#endif
    // ...
};
```

**Request 2: I could not find a *simple* (as in: not unnecessarily complicated template-based) and clean way to express a compile-time optional inheritance at the `A_implementation`-level. Can you?**

Comment: Why not make `optional_implementation_;` a unique pointer towards appropriate interface and fill it only when the compile-time option is on? Make `optional_interface()` return pointer instead of reference to let to users know they might get nothing. Generally, it is a bad idea to fiddle with interfaces - it messes up ABI and whole idea of general common interface. Better just to give option to the interface to return "no data" or this "feature is not supported".

Comment: @ALX23z, good point, but every coin has two sides , I guess. When you're thinking about consistent ABI, as I am an embedded developer, I'm thinking about not linking in unnecessary stuff. Let's just say that ABI consistency is not a requirement for my application. My question is really about returning non-const references (or pointers for that matter, it does not make a difference from that perspective) to "interfaces to" member variables. Since you do not seem to have a problem with that aspect, I will take your comment as a positive opinion.

Comment: the only problem with returning references to member variables and using them in long term is that they are invalidated upon move - which causes code to be clunky for development - but it might not be an issue in your case.

Comment: @ALX23z, applicable in my case or not, it's still a pretty scary issue. You're forcing me to think further, thanks. I think I have just found a better solution for my problem. I will probably post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Better solution

Based on a comment from @ALX23z about invalidation of member variable reference upon move, I am now rejecting my initial solution (original post). That invalidation problem would not be an issue for my case, but I am in search of a generic pattern.

As usual, the solution is obvious once one has found it.

First a summary of my initial problem.

Say that I have a software updater interface (or any interface, this is just an example):

```
struct Software_updater {
    virtual ~Software_updater() = default;
    virtual void action1(const Input1& input1) = 0;
    virtual void action2() = 0;
    virtual bool action3(const Input2& input2) = 0;
    virtual Data1 info1() = 0;
    virtual Data2 info2() = 0;
    // etc.
};
```

A `B_software_updater` can update two images: an application image, and a boot loader image. Therefore, it wants to provide two instances of the `Software_updater` interface.

A solution that is better than the one in my original post is to declare a `B_application_updater` and a `B_boot_loader_updater`, constructed from a `B_software_updater&`, outside of `B_software_updater`, and instantiated by client code.

```
class B_application_updater : public Software_updater {
    B_application_updater(B_software_updater&);
    // ...
};
class B_boot_loader_updater : public Software_updater {
    B_application_updater(B_boot_loader_updater&);
    // ...
};
```

It does have the drawback of forcing the client code to create three objects instead of only one, but I think that the cleanliness outweighs that drawback.

This will work for the optional interface too (see original post):

```
class A_optional_implementation : public Optional_interface {
    A_optional_implementation(A_implementation&);
};
```

`A_optional_implementation` will be declared outside of `A_implementation`.

Applications that do not need that interface will simply not instantiate `A_optional_implementation`.

## Additional thoughts

### This is an application of the adapter design pattern!

Basically, what this answer comes down to:

- An `Interface` class.
- An `Implementation` class that does the job, but does not really care about the interface. It does not inherit `Interface`. The point of this is that `Implementation` could "do the job" corresponding to several interfaces, without the complexity and drawbacks of multiple inheritance (name conflicts, etc.). It could also do the job corresponding to several instances of the same interface (my case above).
- An `Interface_adapter` class that takes an `Implementation&` parameter in its constructor. It inherits `Interface`, i.e. it effectively implements it, and that is its only purpose.

Taking a step back, I realize that this is simply an application of the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) (although `Implementation`in this case does not necessarily need to implement any externally defined interface - its interface is just its public member functions)!

### An intermediate solution: leave the adapter classes inside the implementation class

In the solution above, I specify that the adapter classes are declared outside of the implementation classes. While this seems logical for the traditional adapter pattern case, for my case, I could just as well declare them inside the implementation class (like I did in the original post) and make them public. The client code would still have to create the implementation and adapter objects, but the adapter classes would belong to the implementation namespace, which would look nicer.